# Is there a way to set and draw every pixel using opengles on android ?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I don't know anything about OpenGLES, I don't understand anything about it.. I am looking for a way to fill my entire screen with, for example, an array which contains RGB values, and I am looking for a fast method (set pixels using bitmap from the graphics library of android isn't fast enough).
I don't know how I am supposed to do this and I'm stuck. If anyone could help me, I would be very grateful, thanks..

Comment: How are you generating these pixels?  Most likely you're doing something very wrong here.

Comment: I didn't try anything, I just want to know if it is possible to draw pixels with an array using opengles (for example a byte array which has R, G, B value or RGBA).. I don't really understand your question I'm sorry, my intentions may have been unclear..?

Comment: If you're generating a giant array of pixels, that itself is probably doing something very wrong. That's an incredibly inefficient way of doing things. Why/how are you doing that?

Comment: I want to draw shapes pixel by pixel, probably inefficient but probably a great way to learn. Why is it bad ? Isn't it used for playing videos, for example..? I guess a video has to display something like an array who constantly change..

Comment: It is possible to do this with OpenGL ES, but it's quite a bit of code to do so. You might want to use SDL2's functions for this to save yourself having to use GL if you're wanting to do pixel manipulation in software. With that being said, if you want to learn how to do graphics, learn how to do rendering with OpenGL ES itself rather than manipulating byte arrays.